# MVC - Display objects depending on user's property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Alright, I have three probably stupid questions but I would very much appreciate input or hints or links from you since I am stuck:

There is an entity "Portfolio" with lists of stocks, options, futures and with a groupID and there are several users with groupIDs. **I want to show only the Portfolio to a user where his and the Portfolio's groupID are the same.**

So far, I have a viewmodel with lists of all entities needed for that view. In the view itself, all portfolios, all stocks, all options etc. are displayed instead of just those with the same group as the user.

Besides the fact that it does not work, I feel it is wrong to try and filter for same group of user and Portfolio in the view like this:

```
@if (portfolio.GroupID == Model.UserProfiles.Find(m => m.UserName == User.Identity.Name).GroupId)
```

**Q1:** I would be glad for a hint/an example/a link in the right direction of how to manage something like this.

**Q2:** Am I using the concept of a viewmodel totally wrong here?

```
    public List<StockPosition> StockPositions { get; set; }
    public List<OptionPosition> OptionPositions { get; set; }
    public List<FuturePosition> FuturePositions { get; set; }
    public List<BondPosition> BondPositions { get; set; }
    public List<FondsPosition> FondsPositions { get; set; }
    public List<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
    public List<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
```

**Q3:** The PortfolioController hands over a list of pretty much everything to the view. Should filtering be implemented here?

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new PortfolioExtended();
        viewModel.StockPositions = db.StockPositions.ToList();
        viewModel.BondPositions = db.BondPositions.ToList();
        viewModel.FuturePositions = db.FuturePositions.ToList();
        viewModel.OptionPositions = db.OptionPositions.ToList();
        viewModel.FondsPositions = db.FondsPositions.ToList();
        viewModel.Portfolios = db.Portfolios.ToList();
        viewModel.UserProfiles = db.UserProfiles.ToList();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Is it a currently logged in user viewing the Index page?

Comment: Yes, users have to log in before seeing the Index page and each user has a groupId assigned.

Comment: Are you able to get the current user's ID in the Index action?

Comment: Hm I wouldn't know how to do that but this should be possible or not? I use SimpleMembership and have extended the UserProfile for a field GroupID.

Comment: Ah alright I should get the current user with User.Identity.Name in the controller action..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:** Here's how I would approach this:

In the `Index` action, narrow everything down to the things relevant to the current User.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new PortfolioExtended();
    var currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
    var userGroupId = db.UserProfiles.Single(x => x.UserName == currentUser).GroupId;
    viewModel.Portfolios = db.Portfolios.Where(x => x.GroupID == userGroupId);
    // Anything else you need to intialise
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

This assumes that usernames are unique in the UserProfiles list and will limit the view to having only the relevant portfolios.

Did you say that the other entities (futures, bonds etc) are part of a portfolio? If that's the case, you should be able to access them by using `portfolio.Whatever`, rather than passing them all as lists of their own. If they're separate, ignore this bit.

**Q2** The concept of a `ViewModel` is to pass through everything you need to display on the `View`. In this case, it seems like you've gotten it right, you might not need *everything* you have there, but that's the general idea.

**Q3** Filtering should happen in the controller, yes. Winnow it down to just the things you need.

The difference between Q2 and Q3's answers there is that the `ViewModel` has properties for all the things you *could* need in the view, and the controller action filters *those* lists etc down to the things you need in this specific instance.

Comment: Thank you very much, Colm! Especially for your explanation, I figured out that I don't need the viewmodel because every other asset is contained in the portfolio-entity through foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Use the controller to do any filtering of data.  Only add data to the model that will actually be used by the view.

So filter your Portfolio based on the group and user identifiers inside the controller action.

```
var currentUserProfile = db.UserProfiles.Where(p => p.UserName == User.Identity.Name).Single();
int groupId = currentUserProfile.GroupId;
viewModel.StockPositions = db.StockPositions.Where(p => p.GroupId == groupId).ToList();
// etc.
```

When in the view, show the data contained in the view, trusting that it's for the user/group.

Comment: Thank you very much for that, Matt. I'll try right after a smoke.